# Tableau show legends for lines charts on dual axis?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 lines in a chart and i used dual axis on them. For each line, i manually picked colors for them through the MARKS card.

[image]

Now I need a legend to show what each line and their color represent but i dont see any way to do it. When i put one of the pill on the colors box, it gives me a gradient of colors on my trend line which is not the color i manually picked by clicking on the colors box.

How can i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "All" marks card (the top one), put Measure Names on the color shelf

Comment: Thanks, I realized it allowed me to filter on which values i wanted for the color legend without affecting other pills in my charts :)